Optimization of Objective Functions Involving the Sum of Squares of Diagonal Elements in Matrices
How can I optimize an objective function that includes the sum of the squares of diagonal elements? For example, for the optimization problem
$$\text{tr}((A^TB - I)(A^TB - I)^T) - \sum_{i=1}^n (A^TB)_{i,i}^2 = \text{tr}(A^TBB^TA) - \text{tr}(A^TB) - \text{tr}(B^TA) + \text{tr}(I) - \sum_{i=1}^n (A^TB)_{i,i}(A^TB)_{i,i}^T,$$
$$s.t. \quad \text{tr}(BB^T)<a$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ are the optimization variables, $a$ is a constant. it seems difficult to write the first-order derivative of the term $\sum_{i=1}^n (A^TB)_{i,i}^2$. I attempted to optimize each column of A and B separately. Specifically, for the $i$-th column $B_i$, the objective function is
$$\text{tr}(A^TB_i(B_i)^TA) - \text{tr}(A^TB_i) - \text{tr}(A(B_i)^T) - \text{tr}((A_i)^TB_i(B_i)^TA_i),$$
and then solve it using the Lagrangian multiplier methods. We can use first-order optimality condition to solve $A_i$ However, my code implementation seems to fail to converge. Is this because this block coordinate descent method is very sensitive to initial values? If not using this method of optimizing each column separately, what other methods could be used?

Alright, thank you for your suggestion. I think that the subproblems optimized by columns are all convex, so I don’t understand why they can’t reach a global solution. Perhaps I am not very familiar with some aspects of convex optimization. Could you help me identify them? Thank you so much. @goldboy

Let $M :=A^{T}B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$. The problem is equivalent to
$$\min_M\, tr\left(MM^{T}-2M - M\odot M\right).$$ Trace of the first and third term are the same by setting M to be diagonal matrix. Thus, the objective is unbounded from below.

Thank you for response. What should I do if $M$ is not a diagonal matrix?

non-zero off diagonal elements can only increase the objective value
